# Session Error in Safari on IOS6 while Chrome works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ios6, mobile-safari

I call a Webapplication from my build in UIWebview and get a session error every time, while it works fine on chrome. The error can be repoduced in Safari on my iOS6 device. In iOS5.1 Safari runs more stable.

The thing that make me wondering is, that Chrome works fine. As I have read, they even use a UIWebView, so what is Chrome doing right? Can I do anything in my App to make UIWebView more stable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to disable NSURLCache on iOS6.